# How to run vscode in WSL command line

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I run `code .` in root, and WSL automatically installs need components and open VSCode, just as [official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) said.

Problem is, when I switch back to a non-root user (say, user `papa`), running `code` or `code .` just won't work. How to solve this problem? I wish to either let `papa` "know" that I installed code components, or somehow install vscode components manually under user `papa`.

Comment: How are you switching the user?  If you `su - papa`, then the WSL path isn't going to be populated with the Windows path.  However, if you restart WSL with `wsl -u papa`, then it *should* have VSCode in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. The bug-report is found at
[wsl: allow to run with a non-default user #286](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/286).

The last entry in the post dates from May 27, 2021.
For the moment, there is no solution by Microsoft, and the bug doesn't
even seem to have come to the attention of the developers (yet?).

In another similar bug-report
[Change vscode user in remote-WSL #3631](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3631),
the only answer was:

> To start the remote window as a different user, you must change the wsl default user. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#change-the-default-user-for-a-distribution